# gmail message id to url mapping

Tags: gmail, gmail-api, gmail-imap, gmail-addons

I am using gmail API
https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/get
to get messages
However, the API require "id:The ID of the message to retrieve."

Is there a way to get this message id from the gmail web interface?

Is there a mapping for FMfcgxvxBXrzJnSqVwmZKSZNmvSNNrQb to the messageID from the API?
FMfcgxvxBXrzJnSqVwmZKSZNmvSNNrQb is the unique message url obtained when the email is opened from the browser.
https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/#search/FMfcgxvxBXrzJnSqVwmZKSZNmvSNNrQb

Comment: AFAIK, this is not yet available in the API. Try posting a [feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=191645&template=823908) for this, it can help class that has support multiple timezones (students studying in different timezones).